# What are version and revision of a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management, sorting

The docs for the [nnn file manager](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/wiki/Usage#program-options) says that nnn is able to sort a list of files on the basis of:

> apparent disk usage / disk usage / extension / revision / size / time / version

But what are the "revision" and "version" of a file?

Comment: If you do not have kind of CVS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) you do not have version of the file

Comment: @RomeoNinov: If you have a list of filenames which includes files named `foo-9.0.0.zip` and `foo-11.2.3.zip`, then you can reasonably conclude that these are two versions of the same program, and it would make sense to sort them based on the version: `foo-9.0.0.zip` before `foo-11.2.3.zip` instead of based on purely the file name: `foo-11.2.3.zip` before `foo-9.0.0.zip` because `1` comes before `9`. This is a standard feature of many file managers for decades and does not require CVS.

Comment: I have added a "Linux" tag.  Windows deals with revisions and versions completely different than Linux does.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, your words are pure speculation. These are just filenames and the numbers may or may not have meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The [*Features*](https://github.com/jarun/nnn#features) section in the [`README`](https://github.com/jarun/nnn#readme) says:

> Case-insensitive version (aka natural) sort

To me, that sounds like n³ can detect version numbers in file names like [`nnn-v4.8.tar.gz`](https://github.com/jarun/nnn/releases/download/v4.8/nnn-v4.8.tar.gz) and sort them in a way that makes sense as a version number.

For example, if you did a simple *lexicographic text sort*, you might end up with something like this:

1. 1.0
2. 10.0 (because `1` comes before `2`)
3. 2.0
4. 20.0
5. 20.0-alpha (because shorter matches come before longer matches)

Whereas a *version-aware sort* would produce:

1. 1.0
2. 2.0
3. 10.0
4. 20.0-alpha
5. 20.0

The [*Semantic Versioning Specification*](https://semver.org/) contains [one specific example of how to sort versions](https://semver.org/#spec-item-11). I don't know if this is exactly what n³ uses, but most version-sorting alogorithms work in a similar way.

I don't know exactly what n³ means by "Revision", but there are application which include a Revision number either in the filename or in the content metadata.